# Flutter - NoSuchMethodError: Class '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot>' has no instance method 'then'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to retrieve data from my sub collection. It should return the list of friendid.[image]

But I keep getting the NoSuchMethodError snapshot has no instance method then error with the code below.
The error is at `firebaseMethods.getFriend(Constant.currentId).then((value)` line.
[image]

```
  Widget friendList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: friendlistStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return FriendTile(
                      snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["friendid"]);
                },
              )
            : Container();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserFriend();
    super.initState();
  }

  getUserFriend() async {
    Constant.currentId =
        await HelperFunctions.getUserIdSharedPreference(Constant.currentId);
    setState(() {
      firebaseMethods.getFriend(Constant.currentId).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          friendlistStream = value;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

The code for firestore is as below.

```
getFriend(String ownerid) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(ownerid)
        .collection("friends")
        .snapshots();
  }
```

I had tried hardcoding the `Constant.currentId` to the actual ID that I wanted to retrieve but still having the same error. What should I do to display the list of friendid correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future getFriend(String ownerid) async {
return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc(ownerid)
    .collection("friends")
    .get();
```

}

.then() is used for futures so your getFriend() method needs to return a Future
If you want to use the Stream than you need to use a StreamBuilder instead of calling a function in initState
This might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkKEWHfy99Y&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! It works by just using Future at getFriend().